# Why doesn't the animation occur within the modal/lightbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I was wondering why this animation was not working while in the lightbox.

If you click on the "Herro" box it expands and you can see a **smooth animation** occur.

If you click on "hee" a lightbox/modal will open up. if you click on the "herro" inside the lightbox/modal, you will notice that it **does not have the smooth animation.**

To what do i attribute the animation not happening. Similar effects have happened to me before and i was wondering what causes this and how can i fix this here?

This is the code in the html, when i load it up in the lightbox, the animation does not work. does this have to do with how i am calling the script in the head?

```
<ul class="cd-accordion-menu a animated">
<li class="has-children">
    <input type="checkbox" name ="group-1" id="group-1">
    <label for="group-1"> herro </label>

    <ul>
        <li>hello</li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

[Demo on site](http://nycmetroplus.com/iso/)

[view files on github if you want to download the files or take a closer look](https://github.com/shadowtrixz/test)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check Javascript console. it says no JBox and your refrence scripts not exists or taking too much time and it timeouts.

> http://code.jboxcdn.com/0.3.2/jBox.min.js
>
> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
>       Uncaught ReferenceError: jBox is not defined (index):32

Short key for developers tools
**Google Chrome** F12
**Mozilla FireFox** F12

Solution

> **Fix the script path.**

Comment: i checked, i only saw the "true" "false" in console.  how do i fix the script path? i also noticed that in the lightbox, when i click on the "herro" it does not print "true" "false" in console. console only prints the one on the homepage without the lightbox.

Comment: Download Script manually from http://code.jboxcdn.com/0.3.2/jBox.min.js and add it to your project.

Comment: I still have the problem. did you check it out at the link?

Comment: so look, when you click on the box with the text "herro" you will see a smooth animation.  Click on the one inside the modal and no smooth animation. the box just expands with no animation.

Comment: checked on chrome and Mozilla Firefox its looks fine here, since the height of the Modal box is less than the other that's why it doesn't look smooth, because  you are comparing both and both have different heights. Make the height of both boxes same and then check

Comment: ahh, had to refresh cache, also tried on fire fox and it worked. Thanks